# How do you create directories based on filenames and move identically-named files (different formats) into them?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of files in different formats, all named identically (i.e., file1.txt, file1.conf, file2.txt, file2.conf, etc.) in the same directory. What I'm trying to do is create directories based on the filename and then move all of the corresponding files into that newly-created directory.

I found several tangentially-related questions across Stack Overflow that I tried to bring together:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in ./*.txt ./*.conf ; do
  [[ -e "$f" ]] 
  dir="${f%.*}"
  if [ ! -d "$dir" ] ; then
  mkdir "$dir"
  fi
  mv "$f".* "$dir"

done
```

I admittedly am brand new to working in the shell, so I don't fully understand the parameterization yet. I think in a `for` loop I'd use the `-e` flag to check that a .txt or .conf file exists, the filename gets assigned to `$f`, creates a directory named `$f` it doesn't already exist, and after that moves all files named `$f` with any sort of extension into the directory.

Comment: You could use `./*.*` to do this for every file with an extension. Otherwise, I would explicitly specify all the extensions to target. Either way, use `mv "$f" "$dir"` (not `"$f".*`), use `[[ -e "$f" ]] || continue`, and you also really need to check that `$dir` is not an exisiting file, or you'll overwrite it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this I think.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for file in ./*.txt ./*.conf; do
    basename="${file##*/}" # Remove the path e.g. ./file.txt ==> file.txt
    targetDir="${basename%.*}" # Remove the extension e.g. file.txt ==> file
    mkdir -p "$targetDir" # Create a new directory if not exist. Ignore otherwise.
    echo mv "$file" "$targetDir" # Move file to the target directory.
done
```

To do the job, remove the last `echo`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! I think it's literally trying to move `./*txt` because I get the following errors:


`mv: cannot stat './*.txt': No such file or directory mv: cannot stat './*.conf': No such file or directory`


I tried echo-ing the other lines, and think targetDir isn't being assigned, possibly because it's treating \*.txt as a literal? This pops up for both the txt and conf files (I'm using || to identify what would be new lines):

`basename=*.txt   ||  targetDir=   ||  mkdir -p   ||  mv *.txt`

Comment: That means, you're in a wrong directory. First `cd` to the directory that contains the files, then use `ls` to verify. If you're seeing *.txt and *.conf, then you're in a right directory. First run the script without removing the `echo`, after you're sure that the output is correct, and then you can remove that `echo`. Make sure the script in the same directory too.

Comment: Thank you! Would you mind explaining what the special characters do, exactly? I get that $ identifies a variable, but not how curly braces determine the file's basename and &.* strips out the file extension. From what I was reading {} builds an array, but does that array just consist of every .txt/.conf file it finds? The last two lines make perfect sense to me.

Comment: I didn't use arrays here. It's all about **parameter expansion**. You learn more [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html)